# Would like + ed verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verbs, auxiliary

Yesterday I received an email with a weird construction.

> I have a 1X40HQ I would like pulled from Location to Location.

1x40HQ refers to a container.

For me, the verb in the past tense after "would like" sounds odd.
I put it into a few grammar checker tolls.
In Grammarly, no mistakes were found.
In Ginger and scribens, the error was spotted only after sentence separation(adding period).

> I have a 1X40HQ**.** I would like pulled from Location(rail) to Location.

I started thinking that maybe these tools don't find mistakes because they treat it as perfect tense.
This makes sense if adding period only, would find the error(not in Grammarly, though).

So my question is.

Does my logic make any sense?

Or maybe there is something else that I simply don't know?

Like for example, dropping "to be" (because it is implied) in causal writing/talk?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Think of it as "I have a 1X40HQ **that** I would like **to have** pulled..."  Does that help?

Comment: "Pulled" is a past participle verb and "pulled from location to location" is thus a past-participial clause. Past-participials like this are 'bare' passives, as evident from the admissibility of a _by_ phrase. The bracketing is "[a 1X40HQ [(that) I would like [___ pulled from location to location]]]", where the gap notation '___' refers to "1X40HQ" functioning as head of the noun phrase and the semantic (understood) subject of the subordinate "pulled" clause.

Comment: @BillJ
Thanks. By " as evident from the admissibility of a by phrase"
Do you mean that it is allowed to use it here?  for example 
"I have a 1X40HQ**.** I would like pulled from Location(rail) to Location by someone" ?  but it is not included as we tend not to when it is NONIDENTIFYING INFORMATION? For rest, I need some more time to sink it into my brain and do additional reading. If I would have an additional question. I will be back.  It makes totally sense thank you for your help!

Comment: @stangdon For sure, it sounds better for me, but what is the logic behind it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Such passive clauses are called 'short passives' because they don't have a _by_ phrase.

Comment: Incidentally, the passive clause "pulled from Location to Location" is referred to as a 'bare passive' because it lacks the usual "be" marker. It's functioning as complement of "like". I can post a full answer if you liked.

Comment: @BillJ It would be awesome, that is, if it is not a problem.

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you!

Comment: @BillJ p.s one more thing: "the gap notation '___' refers to "1X40HQ" functioning as head of the noun phrase and the semantic (understood) subject of the subordinate "pulled" clause. " shouldn't be functioning as an object if it is passive voice?

Comment: I've posted an answer. I hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have a 1X40HQ* [*(that) I would like* ___ [*pulled from location to location*]].

This is quite a tricky sentence to analyse. There are two important points to make:

First, the bit in outer brackets is a relative clause modifying "1X40HQ".

Second, the bit in inner brackets is a 'bare' passive clause in a complex catenative construction functioning as complement of "like". The intervening noun phrase, marked by the gap notation '___', is the syntactic object of "like" (i.e. "1X40HQ") in the relative clause as well as the semantic (*understood*) subject of the passive clause.

Note that "pulled" is a past participle verb here, which explains why "pulled from location to location" is a past-participial clause. Past-participials like this are called 'bare' passives because they lack the usual "be" verb, but they are clearly passive as evident from the admissibility of a *by* phrase.

Comment: Thank you @BillJ I will dive into it deeper tomorrow. Once more time thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 1X40HQ I would like pulled from Location to Location.

The original sentence is fine.

Edit after comments from @BillJ

*I would like pulled from Location to Location* has a similar form as the following example from [CambridgeDictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like)

> used in requests:

> [ + past participle ] **I would like** the whole lot **finished** by the weekend.  [emphasis added]

On the other hand, adding a full stop after *1X40HQ*, as shown in your 2nd example, would create a fragment after that full stop.

> *I would like pulled from Location to Location

Comment: The omission of the subordinator "that" does not make it a 'reduced' relative clause, but simply a 'bare' one. A so-called reduced relative clause has a non-finite clause as modifier, whereas "I would like pulled from Location to Location" is, of course, a finite relative clause.

Comment: @Seowjooheng Singapore Thank you. I was looking for this but somehow missed this  Like BillJ mentioned it is a passive voice which for some reason I didn't even consider.

Comment: @Maciej Wakowski, you are welcome.   Please remember to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.